# Listing pathnames of directory after inputing two strings

Tags: c, linux

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void list_items(char * p)
{
    DIR * d ;
    struct dirent * e ;

    d = opendir(p) ;
    if (d == 0x0)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;

    for (e = readdir(d) ; e != 0x0 ; e = readdir(d)) {
            if (e->d_type == DT_DIR /* directory */ ||
                            e->d_type == DT_REG /* regular file */ ) {
                    printf("%s\n", e->d_name) ;

            }
    }
  }

 int main(int args, char ** argv)
{
    if (args != 2)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE) ;

    list_items(argv[1])  ;
}
```

So this prints out this:

```
./a.out /usr //the input
 hello
 bin
```

I need to put the directory ie the /usr and the file name so the program compares the filename under the directory and return all the pathnames
so i need an outcome such as this example

```
./a.out /usr hello 
 /usr/bin/hello
 /usr/exe/hello
 /usr/python/hello
```

What must add to this code to get this outcome? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to check that the argument count is 3 (not 2), pass the suffix to the `list_items()` function, and print the directory name and suffix as well as the file name.  Along with some other tarting up, that leads to:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void list_items(char *dirname, char *suffix)
{
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *e;

    d = opendir(dirname);
    if (d == 0x0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open directory %s\n", dirname);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (e = readdir(d); e != 0x0; e = readdir(d))
    {
        if (e->d_type == DT_DIR /* directory */ ||
            e->d_type == DT_REG /* regular file */)
        {
            printf("%s/%s/%s\n", dirname, e->d_name, suffix);
        }
    }
    closedir(d);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s directory suffix\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    list_items(argv[1], argv[2]);
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ ls inc
README.md   emalloc.h   jlss.h      range.h     wraphead.h
aoscopy.h   filter.h    kludge.h    reldiff.h
chkstrint.h gcd.h       microsleep.h    stderr.h
debug.h     isqrt.h     posixver.h  timer.h
$ ./dir61 inc podunk
inc/./podunk
inc/../podunk
inc/kludge.h/podunk
inc/emalloc.h/podunk
inc/range.h/podunk
inc/debug.h/podunk
inc/posixver.h/podunk
inc/microsleep.h/podunk
inc/reldiff.h/podunk
inc/isqrt.h/podunk
inc/README.md/podunk
inc/timer.h/podunk
inc/gcd.h/podunk
inc/stderr.h/podunk
inc/jlss.h/podunk
inc/aoscopy.h/podunk
inc/filter.h/podunk
inc/chkstrint.h/podunk
inc/wraphead.h/podunk
$
```

If you don't want to mess with `.` and `..`, you have to exclude them in the test too.